# using layout in themes from inside module Yii PHP

Tags: php, layout, yii

In Yii application I used own **theme**(demirTheme) have **modules**(retail, corporate), and **layouts**(main, layout_retail, layout_corporate).

When rendering one page(ex index) I want my app to render page, related layout (retail vs corporate) and then main accordingly. How can I achieve this?

I read layout tutorials and questions no help. They only mention about changing layout path, setting default layout for module, and so on.

I tried

- to put all layouts in themes layouts folder,
- to put main layout in themes layouts folder and other two in modules layouts folder respectively by their module,
- to put all layouts in protected/view/layouts folder,
- to put all layouts in modules and one copy of main layout for each module
  But can't get it work. I tried changing layout path and other settings.

Is there any way? Have you done layout rendering like this? Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `public $layout='//layouts/layout_retail';` in the controller you want to apply the layout to (so in every controller in the retail module for example). The views should be in "protected/view/layouts"

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#layout-detail

I am also sure you can put the layouts in the modules map. I however use the above methode for our admin module.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebModule#layout-detail

EDIT:
You retail or corporate layout should be then like the code underneath. So the retail or corporate layout would be inside the main layout. Clearly it should contain more then just this, but the content of you layouts should be within `$this->beginContent('//layouts/main');` and `$this->endContent();`

```
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?> //main
<div id="content"> 
    <?php echo $content; ?> //viewOfRetail
</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

Comment: Ok, when I add set $layout variable for each controller, or for each module, modules rendering layout_retail and layout_corporate accordingly. But they didn't wrapped inside **main** layout. Where to put main layout?

Comment: When I rendering, I want this layout wrappings:  viewsOfRetail->layout_retail->main,  viewsOfCorporate->layout_corporate->main

Answer (score 0):

For the newcomers: in many help forums of the Internet, when someone asks about theming a module, everyone suggests a path alias to the themes folder, and I disagree with those other forums. I think this is wrong, because it implies modules to be splitted, and modules are supposed to be a black-box that can be used across projects. The advice given in such forums would  only be valid if a theme is shared among several modules. If someone wants to "package" a theme inside a module, she can:
-add an init function to the controller of the module
-inside that init, use the class attribute layout and a path alias, like this, supose a module whose id is "Sample":
then you add, to SampleController.php:

```
public function init() {
    //BELOW: it will use the layouts/main.php inside the module.
    $this->layouts = "sample.views.layouts.main"; 
}
```

Yo can check about path alias here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace